# How to pass credentials to Connect-ExchangeOnline cmdlet programatically

Tags: powershell, office365

I am working within GitHub Actions, using it to run PowerShell scripts. As part of the workflow I request user authentication information (O365 username, pass, mfa). These are then passed as secrets to my script for creating a connection to MS Exchange.

To create a session for local execution I use the following code:
`Connect-ExchangeOnline -UserPrincipalName <user@org.com> -ShowProgress $true`

This currently generates a prompt for me to enter the user pass and mfa, The ideal workflow is that those are passed programmatically and there are no prompts displayed.

I've looked into other authentication methods, and if necessary I can pass a certificate, my desire to pass these directly is for ease of user access and to not have to store new secrets as part of this workflow.

Comment: You can't (securely) include [mfa](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multi-factor_authentication) in a script (only initiate the process). In fact, you can't authorize or trust a script. Instead, you will need to authorize and thrust the user account that runs the script.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

After a couple days of searching it would seem there is not a current workflow for this authentication method. While I could technically link to a secondary service account to acquire this information at runtime, it would be impossible to actually secure that connection, making the entire authentication process pointless. Passing a cert thumbprint is the suggested way of authenticating without having an active session.